# Using document.location=file_url.mp3 to trigger download from JS - incorrect?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some legacy code here, and the way it triggers .mp3 file playback is like so:

```
document.location = file_url.mp3;
```

Which in turn prompts user to download a file or plays it (depending on a platform). I just feel this is super-incorrect way of allowing user to play .mp3 files. Can someone specify why exactly this approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
window.location.href = 'file_url.mp3';
});

<a href="no-script.html">Download</a>
```

Using **[preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#event.preventDefault.28.29)**

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty and hidden HTML div

```
<div id="player" style="display:none"></div>
```

Then add this bit of JavaScript

```
function playMp3(stop) {
   var div = document.getElementById('player');
   if (stop) {
       div.innerHTML = '';
   } else {
       div.innerHTML = '<audio autoplay><source src="fule_url.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
   }
}
```

Now to play file

```
playMp3();
```

to stop playing call

```
playMp3(1);
```

Comment: @Dannyboy that works on iOS, haven't tried in android but mostl likely it will work as well.